# Border change color on hover

Tags: html, css, prestashop-1.6

I want a right border to change from green to black on hover.
The CSS I tried doesn't work. How do ?

---

Html :

```
<li class="">
<a class="xclass" title="1stmenu" href="mylink">mytext</a>
```

---

CSS :

```
.sf-menu > li {  
  float: left;  
  border-right: 2px solid;  
  border-color : #fff #00a54f;  
               }  
.sf-menu > li.sfHover > a,  
  .sf-menu > li > a:hover, .sf-menu > li.sfHoverForce > a {  
    border-color : #fff black;  
    color: #00a54f; }
```

---

If anyone can also throw in some information about how the hover script is executed, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: You've not added the complete code. The relevant code you've added is missing with .sf-menu, sfHover, .sf-menu and .sfHoverForce CSS class. Added your complete code to ensure people can provide you most suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I noticed your html was incomplete and your css was too complex so I completed and simplified it by adding the ul element and styling the non-hover state for the a href:

```css
.sf-menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sf-menu li {  
  float: left;   
}

.sf-menu li a {
    border-right: 2px solid;  
  border-color : #fff #00a54f;
  }

.sf-menu > li.sfHover > a,  
  .sf-menu > li > a:hover, .sf-menu > li.sfHoverForce > a {  
    border-color : #fff black;  
    color: #00a54f; 
  }
```

```html
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li class="">
<a class="xclass" title="1stmenu" href="mylink">mytext</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It was too complex for my beginner skills and know-how. You gave me a clean sheet to build on.  
Most of the other stuff were scipt animations that I didn't need for the time being. I'll discover them later once I got a good hold between CSS and Html.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use like:

```
.sf-menu li {
border-color : green;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
border-color : black;
}
```

I hope it would work.